# Dell 5471 Ubuntu 16.04 Fan Noise and overheating

Tags: dell, fan, fancontrol, dell-vostro

My computer has been taken 2 months. In the First months computer if hard work or weather is too hot then computer was starting fan and was fnishing.
Now, when i open the computer fan starting (for example if i open the just browser fan noise starting and keep going forever :( ) Something is wrong i dont know. Please help me about this problem.

- I made BIOS Flash Update.
- I dowloanded i8kmom (but that program Switched on and off at 1 second intervals so. I removed that.

Sensors output:

```
    acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +38.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +38.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +38.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +37.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3065 RPM
CPU:            +39.0°C  
Ambient:        +35.0°C  
SODIMM:         +37.0°C  
Other:          +40.0°C
```

lspci | grep VGA output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
```

lspci output:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev c1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should overtake the fan speed control from the BIOS.
You can install [dell-bios-fan-control](https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control) and set it up as service.

```
git clone https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control.git
cd dell-bios-fan-control
make
sudo mv dell-bios-fan-control /usr/bin/
```

Than, create a service file /etc/systemd/system/dell-bios-fan-control.service with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disables BIOS control of fans at boot.
Before=i8kmon.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dell-bios-fan-control 0
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/dell-bios-fan-control 1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, enable the service using

```
sudo systemctl enable dell-bios-fan-control
```

Than start the both services (i8kmon and dell-bios-fan-control). It should be fine.